# nested nsmutablearrays shorthand

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I would like to use objective c shorthand to access nested nsmutablearrays.

```
NSMutableArray *board;
board[0] = [NSMutableArray new];
board[1] = [NSMutableArray new];
board[2] = [NSMutableArray new];
board[0][0] = @"a";
board[0][1] = @"b";
board[0][2] = @"c";
board[1][0] = @"d";
board[1][1] = @"e";
board[1][2] = @"f";
board[2][0] = @"g";
board[2][1] = @"h";
board[2][2] = @"i";
for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        NSLog( @"%@", board[r][c]);
   }  
}
```

gives a lot of nulls.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah, you never created the root array.  (In ARC, `new` and `array` are essentially interchangeable.)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought at first glance without really doing any investigation..

you have not initialized the first array..
also you should probably be using "array" to initialize not "new"

```
NSMutableArray *board = [NSMutableArray array];
board[0] = [NSMutableArray array];
board[1] = [NSMutableArray array];
board[2] = [NSMutableArray array];
board[0][0] = @"a";
board[0][1] = @"b";
board[0][2] = @"c";
board[1][0] = @"d";
board[1][1] = @"e";
board[1][2] = @"f";
board[2][0] = @"g";
board[2][1] = @"h";
board[2][2] = @"i";
for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
        NSLog( @"%@", board[r][c]);
   }  
}
```

Not 100% if this will solve your problem, I haven't attempted nested arrays in objc like this before.

you Might also try

```
NSMutableArray *board = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3]
```

if it's still not working